# array_slice does not return last values

Tags: php

I don't understand why it isn't working on my machine:

```
$texts = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g');
$whatever = array_slice($texts, 0, -3, true);
dd($whatever);
```

This returns "a, b, c, d", but I want it to return "e, f, g".

And if I write

```
$whatever = array_slice($texts, 0, 4, true);
```

This also return "a, b, c, d"

All I want is to return "e, f, g" [and the manual examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) don’t seem to work on my machine.

**EDIT:** I just saw, if I do:

```
 $whatever = array_slice($texts, -3);
```

I'll get the last 3 elements of the array, but in the wrong order. I want the last array to be first. I guess I need to reverse the array, or is there another way?

Comment: $whatever = array_slice($texts, -3, 3, true);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second parameter is offset, the 3rd param is length, so ideally you want to do:

```
$whatever = array_slice($texts, -3, 3, true)
```

**Edit:**
Just saw you need it backwards...

```
$whatever = array_reverse(array_slice($texts, -3, 3, true))
```

Comment: Thank you. I just understood, that it is not possible to fetch the array, using a foreach-loop. I wanted to use the key of the array element to make a database query to display further information about the element, because it is just a column of a table. Nonetheless Thank you very much for your assistance, I'll have to figure out, how to solve the problem.