# Accessing array top and botton elements

Tags: php, arrays

Here again with arrays.

I have a very large array with this format:

```
pros
 {a,b,c....zx,zy,zz}
cons
 {a,b,c...zx,zy,zz}
```

Im able to read all elements inside the array, but i need list only the first 10 of the sub-array "pros" and the last 10 of the subarray "cons" in reverse mode.

This is what i want to show:

```
Pros:
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
Cons
zz,zy,zx,zw,zv,zu,zt,zs,zr,zq
```

Any ideas how i can extract the info?

EDIT

```
$variable = $myarray;

$compras = array_slice($variable['bids'],0,10,true);
$ventas = array_slice($variable['asks'],-10);

echo "<table border =1 style='font-size: 80%;border-collapse:collapse;'>";
foreach($compras as $key => $value) 
    {
    echo "<tr><td>".number_format($value[0],6)."</td><td>".number_format($value[1],4)."</td></tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
```

This is working as I expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [array\_slice does not return last values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23463231/array-slice-does-not-return-last-values)

Answer (score 0):

get first 10

```
$pros= array_slice($pros_array,0, 10);
```

get last 10

```
$cons = array_reverse(array_slice($cons_array,-10, 10));
```

Comment: Should slice before you reverse to save time complexity.

Comment: Not my downvote, but look again at the OP's desired output.  This solution does not provided the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pros = array_slice($prosArray, 0, 10, true);

$cons = array_reverse(array_slice($consArray, -10));
```

Comment: Still need to reverse cons.

Comment: Not my downvote, but look again at the OP's desired output.  This solution does not provided the correct result.

Comment: @PedroJoseOteroRodriguez That is true.  It was corrected after JasonB posted his answer and told this user about its flaw.  Preserving the keys on the `$pros` array is pointless (I think).

Comment: This answer needs an explanation.   Code-only answers are low value on StackOverflow.  Please edit with the intention to educate the OP and future researchers.

Answer (score 0):

array_slice is a very fast function for grabbing a portion of an array. The arguments include the array, starting offset, and number of elements to slice from the array. That is why we use 0, 10 in the first call. A negative offset starts at that number of elements from the end of the array, so we use -10 to grab the end of the cons array. No need for the number of elements here, it will just go to the end of the array. We reverse the cons array after we have it down to just 10 elements instead of wasting a bunch of time flipping the large array first.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

```
$pros = array_slice($pros, 0, 10);

$cons = array_reverse(array_slice($cons,-10) );
```

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa, the answer has been edited to provide a more complete explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If your multi-dimensional array is as large as you are describing, then you don't want to bog down your process by manipulating these data structures before iterating the modified results.  Just be clever about how you access the data -- no modifications are necessary.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/31b53df60d92f3523cc6cf00af0e34e38c149cee))

```
// generate fake array data:
for($s='a'; $s!=='aaa'; ++$s){
    $array['bids'][]=$s;
}
$array['asks']=$array['bids'];
//var_export($array);

// access only what you desire (no array modifications)
$max_asks=sizeof($array['asks'])-1;
echo "<table border=1 style='font-size:80%;border-collapse:collapse;'>";
for($i=0; $i<10; ++$i){
    echo "\n\t<tr>";
        echo "\n\t\t<td>{$array['bids'][$i]}</td>";
        echo "\n\t\t<td>{$array['asks'][$max_asks-$i]}</td>";
    echo "\n\t</tr>";
}
echo "\n</table>";
```

Output:

```
<table border=1 style='font-size:80%;border-collapse:collapse;'>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>zz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>zy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>zx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>zw</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>zv</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>zu</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>zt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>zs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>zr</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>j</td>
        <td>zq</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```